# SQL Query to separate address into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have address data stored in a single column like this:

```
123 Fake St #25
```

I would like to separate this data 3 columns like this:

```
Number   Street     Apt
-----------------------
123      Fake St    #25
```

I figured I can use a combination of trimming and search functions, but I am not sure. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Address can be tricky.  What would the value be of splitting Number and Apt?

Answer (score 2):

The only hint was first blank from start and first blank from end. But - for sure! - there will be addresses which do not fullfill this pattern...

Nevertheless something to start with:

```
DECLARE @addr VARCHAR(100)='123 Fake St #25';

WITH Blanks AS
(
    SELECT @addr AS Addr
          ,CHARINDEX(' ',@addr) AS FirstBlank
          ,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@addr)) AS LastBlankFromBack
)
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(Addr,FirstBlank-1))) AS Number
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Addr,FirstBlank+1,LEN(Addr)-FirstBlank-LastBlankFromBack+1))) AS Street
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(Addr,LastBlankFromBack-1))) AS Apt 
FROM Blanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that address will have a similar pattern as per your example, you may try the following. As already noted cannot get accurate solution if delimiters not known..

Create a function to return scalar value like so

```
        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitGet] (
            @test AS VARCHAR(255)
            ,@field AS VARCHAR(1)
            )
        RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
        AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ReturnValue VARCHAR(255) = '';
            DECLARE @Alpha VARCHAR(255) = '';
            DECLARE @Beta VARCHAR(255) = '';
            DECLARE @Gamma VARCHAR(255) = '';
            DECLARE @ind INT = 1;  
            WHILE (@ind < LEN(@test))
            BEGIN
                IF (ISNUMERIC(substring(@test, @ind, 1)) = 1)
                BEGIN
                    SET @Alpha = @Alpha + cast(substring(@test, @ind, 1) AS NVARCHAR(1));
                    SET @ind = @ind + 1;
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    BREAK;
                END
            END

            SET @Beta = Substring(Substring(@test, @ind, len(@test)), 0, charindex('#', Substring(@test, @ind, len(@test)), 0))
            SET @Gamma = RTRIM(substring(@test, charindex('#', @test, 0), len(@test)));

            IF (@field = 'n') --Numnber
            BEGIN
                SET @ReturnValue = @Alpha;
            END
            ELSE IF (@field = 'a') --Address
            BEGIN
                SET @ReturnValue = @Beta;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN --Apartment
                SET @ReturnValue = @gamma;
            END

            RETURN RTRIM(@ReturnValue)
        END
```

Use it like

```
DECLARE @test varchar(255) = '123 Fake st #25'
SELECT dbo.[SplitGet](@test,'n'),dbo.[SplitGet](@test,'a'),dbo.[SplitGet](@test,'')
```